# AVPlayer video becomes blank when another audio is active

Tags: ios, video, avplayer, interruption

I'm using AVPlayer to play video. And follow these steps

- Open Music app, play a song, and pause it
- Go to my app and play a video
- With the headphone plugged in, press the middle button to resume Music app playback

Then the Music app plays, but my video **goes blank**. From reading [Responding to Interruptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html)

> An audio interruption is the deactivation of your app’s audio
>   session—which immediately stops or pauses your audio, depending on
>   which technology you are using

I understand that my video should pause, but why does it also blank the video?

Only after I press the middle button on the headphone again to pause the Music, then my video goes normal again, but remains in **paused state**

Is this normal behaviour, how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to disable Music app `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`, I found

- [xcode - MPNowPlayingInfoCenter info is not displayed on iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083862/xcode-mpnowplayinginfocenter-info-is-not-displayed-on-ios-8)
- [Remote Control of Your Sound](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch27.html#_remote_control_of_your_sound)

Just call these before playback

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

This will disable Music app, and toggling middle button on the headphone has no effect on us