# how to put an image for every music that playing in lock screen in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, avaudioplayer, lockscreen

I have a player that plays music in swift 3 and want to showing image in lock screen in every songs I searched stack overflow But the codes doesn't helped me please tell me some thing simple because I don't want to use different images ! I just want to show one Image when the app is playing Song in the lock screen 
so here is my codes

```
var player : AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Torpedo", ofType: "mp3")
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)

        }catch {

            //Error

        }


        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {

            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)

        }

        catch {



        }
  player.play()
```

and here is the codes that I used But didn't worked

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyArtist : AudioCenter.sharedInstnce.currentReciter().name,
                                                                 MPMediaItemPropertyTitle : AudioCenter.sharedInstnce.currentSurah()!.name,
                                                                 MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork:MPMediaItemArtwork(image: UIImage(named: "Logo")!)]
```

Comment: Hae you checked solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083862/xcode-mpnowplayinginfocenter-info-is-not-displayed-on-ios-8 ?

Comment: please tell me some thing more simple because I don't want to use different images ! I just want to show one Image when the app is playing Song

Comment: Apart from lock screen image, audio plays fine in locked/background state?

Comment: Check for these two points : 1.Your app must call the UIApplication instance method beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents.
2.Your app’s audio session’s policy must be Playback.

Comment: yes I can hear music when I am in lock screen in real device I turned on back ground mode @Ellen

Comment: please show me some codes here because I want to understand better

Comment: you might need to set the `MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration` and `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate`

Comment: please help me with writing some codes here because I want to understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set Session playback category for Audio session where you will be updating **MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo**

```
       try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: [])
       try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

**EDIT1**

Add in **viewDidLoad** of your VC :

```
self.becomeFirstResponder()
UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

and add 1 more method if it is not there in your VC

```
 override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { return true }
```

**EDIT2**
Try with

```
   try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
```

instead of

```
   try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: [])
```

Comment: I can't see any image codes here can you explain more please?

Comment: where are you updating MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo in code? becuase this is the only way to add image in lock screen. Now you've to check why it is not working in your case? is it same controller which is having all the avaudioplayer code?

Comment: I Just have one view controller if it was your question- I used your codes here and the app doesn't let me to run because of if line error and the error is : argument labels error do not match any available overloads

Comment: ok Thanks It will work But I how can I add image and can I hide controller of the player in lock screen or not?

Comment: you can use same code as mentioned above to set image on lock screen 
  MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyArtist : AudioCenter.sharedInstnce.currentReciter().name,
                                                                 MPMediaItemPropertyTitle : AudioCenter.sharedInstnce.currentSurah()!.name,
                                                                 MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork:MPMediaItemArtwork(image: UIImage(named: "Logo")!)]

Comment: thanks a lot it worked for me can I hide audio controllers in lock screen or not? I just want to show image in the lock screen

Comment: Check Edit2 . It might result into disappear your controls even after reset.This problem is going on ..Disabling controls can be safer option.

Comment: I used Edited 2 codes But when I used that the picture will disappear too :)