# How to Set Artwork Image for MPNowPlayingInfoCenter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mpmediaitem

I've been trying to update the artwork shown for an item in `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` using `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork` as shown in the following code taken from [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/controlling_background_audio)

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "image_here") {
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] =
        MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size) { size in
            return image
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that this sets a smaller image as shown in the photo below in the red square. I'm trying to figure out how to set the image in the larger yellow square, and I can't find any documentation that differentiates between the two.

[image]

**EDIT**

vint's answer below clarified that the smaller icon is the app icon. I am however setting the nowPlayingInfo dictionary successfully since my other metadata is reaching the lock screen controls, like the title (blurred), duration, elapsed playback time). It's just the artwork that appears to not being working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case anyone finds this question and was going crazy like myself, I was able to set the image by correctly resizing my `UIImage` to the incoming `size` parameter given to the `MPMediaItemArtwork` callback function. As it says in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaitemartwork/1649704-init):

> The request handler returns an image in the newly requested size.
> The requested size must be less than the boundsSize parameter.

Then setting my `image` to the incoming `size` parameter with the following extension, the `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork` was finally successfully set.

```
extension UIImage {
    func imageWith(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: newSize)
        let image = renderer.image { _ in
            self.draw(in: CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: newSize))
        }
        return image.withRenderingMode(self.renderingMode)
    }
}

if let image = UIImage(named: "image_here") {
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] =
        MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size) { size in
            // Extension used here to return newly sized image
            return image.imageWith(newSize: size)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you did not successfully set the cover image of the track to
`MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`, The image in red square is your app icon, this is `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`'s default behavior,

I guess you lost the next step

```
// set the info dictionary back to default control center
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default.nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
```

If you has set that, you should find the failed reason, [seed this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30085578/7436060)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't know the smaller icon is the app icon. That's helpful. I have that dictionary set though. I can update everything else (for instance, MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime and MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration as you can see in the screenshot as well as MPMediaItemPropertyTitle. I just blurred out the title). All of the properties get set except the MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork. I'll follow that other answer and see if it helps the issue.