# MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork not getting set in Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, watchos, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I have an audio streaming app which plays live streams using AVPlayer. Everything works as intended and in order to support a good user experience, I set the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter's nowPlayingInfo property with the title, artist and artwork - here is a small snippet:

```
func updateNowPlayingView(withSong song: Song = Song()) {
    let songImage = song.getSongImageAsUIImage()
    let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: songImage.size) { _ -> UIImage in
      return songImage
    }
    
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: song.getSongName(),
                                                       MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: song.getSongArtist(),
                                                       MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyIsLiveStream: true,
                                                       MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: artwork]
}
```

This function is called in the CarPlay Scene delegate and it is called in my AVPlayer sub class for my iOS app and I successfully see the correct meta data in the Command Centre, Lock Screen and Car Play.

For some reason, the artwork does not get displayed in my Apple Watch's Now Playing App:
[image: Now Playing Apple WatchOS]

Seems like it is setting the default / placeholder music icon image.

However, when I play the Apple Music App, I can see they set the Now Playing artwork properly:
[image]

- So what am I doing wrong that my artwork does not get set for Apple Watch ?
- Or am I setting it from the wrong place in my code base ?
- Or do I need to keep an Apple Watch app / Extension / Scene like CarPlay to send NowPlaying data to the Apple Watch Now Playing app ?

Thanks for your time

---

**UPDATE**

I have updated my function to make use of the requested size and resize the the image before setting it in MPNowPlayingInfoCenter, however, this has no impact and the issue still persists.

```
// REF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66093428/1619193
extension UIImage {
  func imageWith(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: newSize)
    let image = renderer.image { _ in
      self.draw(in: CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: newSize))
    }
    return image.withRenderingMode(self.renderingMode)
  }
}

func updateNowPlayingView(withSong song: Song = Song()) {
    let songImage = song.getSongImageAsUIImage()
    
    let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: songImage.size) { size -> UIImage in
      let resizedImage = songImage.imageWith(newSize: size)
      return resizedImage
    }
    
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: song.getSongName(),
MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: song.getSongArtist(),
MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyIsLiveStream: true,
MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: artwork]
}
```

Any ideas would be highly appreciated